# Grails - URL rewriting for all controllers in a package

Tags: grails, url-rewriting

I'm wondering if it's possible to rewrite URL for all controllers in a particular package. I need to change the URL of all controllers in "admin" package to "/admin/$controller" instead of "/$controller", so it can be secured by Spring Security. Thanks very much.

Regards,
Lojza

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So today I implemented the solution according to [this article](http://blog.overzealous.com/post/23304412431/grails-urlmappings-tricks):

```
// AppCtx - check the article above
for (controller in AppCtx.grailsApplication.controllerClasses) {
    def cName = controller.logicalPropertyName
    def packageName = controller.packageName

    if (packageName.contains(".admin") || packageName.contains(".springsecurity")) {
        "/admin/${cName}/$action?/$id?"(controller: cName) {
            constraints {
            }
        }
    } else {
        "/${cName}/$action?/$id?"(controller: cName) {
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not strictly necessary.  You could add the @Secured annotation to each of the admin controllers:

```
@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
class AdminController1 { ... }

@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
class AdminController2 { ... }
```

Or if you're not using annotations, you could map each of the admin controllers to the Spring Security config directly:

```
/adminController1/**=ROLE_ADMIN
/adminController2/**=ROLE_ADMIN
```

But if you really want to put all these controllers under an /admin/ URL prefix, I think you could do it by adding a mapping that manually references each admin controller:

```
"/admin/adminController1/$action?/$id?"(controller: "adminController1")
"/admin/adminController2/$action?/$id?"(controller: "adminController2")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I know about these options. What I needed was the easy way of configuring URLs for all admin controllers, so I don't have to write mapping manually for each of them, but just put them under the right package.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: [Best way to create an Admin section in Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133464/best-way-to-create-an-admin-section-in-grails)

However in this case I always recommend to split up your admin area into an individual grails-embedded-plugin. In here you can do your magic with your custom `UrlMapping`-class. This will keep your main application clean.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean by "grails-embedded-plugin" that I should create a plugin for administration and then install this plugin into my app?

Comment: Usually I have a master-grails project for the main application. Then I use this project as a plugin for a "admin"-grails project. This application contains of the scaffolded controllers and views, some admin controllers and services, and restricting authentication settings. This application I am running as a complete seperate application (possibly running on a different host than the main application).